# TouchJSON with basic HTTP authentication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, basic-authentication, touchjson

I was wondering if anyone has the TouchJSON framework working in conjunction with basic apache HTTP authentication. Essentially the directory of the RESTful webservice that I am calling is secured with basic http authentication. My calls are obviously all returning null now. Has anyone managed to get this working? I could embed the username:password in the URL like https://username:password@www.somewhere.com/webservices/ws.php but for obvious reasons, that is not desired.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Kurtis

Answer (score 0):

TouchJSON does not handle any transfer of data via http, https or any other protocol. Itis merely a parser for converting data between JSON and NSDictionary formats. So it doesn't really matter to TouchJSON how the data exchanged.

Instead you will need to handle the authorization in your data transfer code.